# How can I uses sessions if register_globals is set to off?

Tags: php, session

Because of security reasons, `register_globals` is set to off.
And that sucks, because right now I could really have use of sessions.

How do you guys solve this "problem"?

**UPDATE**

I have tried using $_SESSION, but it's not working. That's why I thought it had something to do with `register_globals` being off.

In my header file, I have the following code:

```
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['test'])) {
  $_SESSION['test'] = "Foo bar";
```

Now, anywhere in my header file, I can output the content of `$_SESSION['test']`.

But I'm not able to output the same content from e.g. page.php file.

Here is an example using Wordpress: example.php

```
//Include the header file
<?php get_header(); ?>

  Here is some text, and this is my session: <?php echo $_SESSION['test']; ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

This will result in an empty Session.

Comment: It's not a "problem", it's a solution. To a huge real problem.

Comment: Make sure session_start() is being called before you use the $_SESSION array, and that your files are included in the correct order.  IE, if page.php is including header.php, make sure page uses $_SESSION only after the line require('header.php').

Comment: Unless you intentionally ommited some PHP tags, you should be seeing "get_header()" in the browser window, and it's never actually being executed.

Comment: That was just me being lazy writing the example. Do I need to include session_start(); in the page.php as well? My require files are always at the top.

Comment: session_start() only needs to be called once per run. Try do a print_r($_SESSION) in the page.php and post the output.

Comment: I'm using session_start() in my header file, before getting / setting sessions. But if I don't have session_start() at the top of the page.php file, the output is blank.

Comment: How did you solve this in the end, Steven?

Comment: @Cawas: By using `session_Start()` on every page. I though it was enough to use it once in the header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All session variables will be in the [`$_SESSION` array](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php). Use `$_SESSION['var']` instead of the globally registered `$var`.

Comment: That's what I thought as well. But my example above isn't working. So I must be missing something..

Comment: @Steven: Are you using the same session? Check out what session ID is used (see `session_id` function). It needs to be the same on every call.

Comment: It seems I have to add session_start() in every file where I will be using sessions. I was hoping it would be enough to set this in the header file...

Comment: @Steven: I thought you already did that. (Although changing *register\_globals* shouldn’t change the session behavior at all.)

Comment: I only set the session_Start() in my header.php. If I don't set it in page.php as well, I'm not able to output my sessions.

Comment: @Steven: Yes, but I thought you’re including your *header.php* in all of your scripts.

Answer (score 5):

Use $_SESSION, see http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php

Comment: Nothing. But when I added session_start() at the top of my page.php file, it worked. It's annoying that I have to include this in every file where I will be using sessions. I was hoping it would be enough to set this in the header file :(

Answer (score 3):

Use the super-global $_SESSION array to store values.  It's contents are stored between requests, and seamlessly serialized and deserialized - don't worry about storing objects or arrays.  A simple example:

```
<?php

 if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
   // user already logged in
 } else {
   // Create a guest user
   $user = new stdClass();
   $user->name = 'guest';
   $user->id = 0;

   $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
 }

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using **iframes** like in **faceook** apps, your sessions may not work in **IE** and **safari**. 
To make it workable in both these browsers use the header code below, just above the **`session_start();`**

- `header('P3P: CP="NOI ADM DEV PSAi COM NAV OUR OTRo STP IND DEM"'); // Require to maintian session in IE`
- `header('P3P:CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT"'); // Require to maintain session in safari`

hope this will help.

Comment: Do you have a reference for those headers? They are pretty cryptic!

Comment: I don't have the reference but they do work. @Rich Bradshaw! If you found one, plz share it with us.

Answer (score 1):

If sessions aren't working, there are a couple of things to check:

- Make sure that the session is being started; call `session_start()` if needed - there's an option (`session.auto_start`) in PHP.ini which can be toggled.
- Check that `session.save_path` points to a valid location which is writeable - check permissions. Under Windows, the default setting is an invalid path for that platform.
- Check the PHP error log for pointers, in case something's going wrong.
- Check the browser isn't blocking session cookies.

You might take a look in the aforementioned `session.save_path` to inspect whether or not session files are being created.

I've assumed use of the default file-based session handler. If using something else (which would require additional configuration), then there might be further troubleshooting steps.

Comment: hmm.. thanks. Didn't know there was a `session.auto_start`. I'm not sure if my ISP allows me to set my own php.ini settings though :( But now I know I have to call session_start() each time before I use sessions. I was hoping it would be enough to call this in my header file - since it's loaded every time.

Answer (score 0):

are you using IIS webserver? 
had similiar "strange" problems with and older IIS version and php4. check your session.save_path in php.ini and assure that your webserver has write access to the directory configured in session.save_path.